# How to get an update NSUserDefault on iOS 4?

Tags: iphone, ios4, nsuserdefaults

I am developing an iPhone application, I encounter a problem on the iOS4 because of multi task.

This application has the default settings defined in a Settings.bundle.
If I run my application then I left it (so it goes in the background).
I'll change the settings and restarts the application (it comes out of standby and method: applicationDidBecomeActive () is called).

Values in NSUserDefault are not updates, but when I leave the application and relaunch. The values are good.

Does someone experience the same problem as me?
Is what I'm doing something wrong?

Thank you for your advice / help.

Comment: Are you refreshing the defaults once your app becomes active again?  If you're not, then you should incase they changed while in the background.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same problem as you, and got around it by calling

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

in `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

For some reason the `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` object you can access in your app isn't synchronized with the actual plist files backing it when an app becomes active again after having been suspended. Calling the `synchronize` method forces a synchronization.

Comment: It's important to emphasize that synchronize MUST be called after you change NSUserDefaults if you want to write those changes to a file. If you don't the changes will be just stored in memory.

Comment: @Mr.Gando That's just not true. `NSUserDefaults` is also periodically synchronized to file automatically.

Answer (score 3):

You need to listen for settings changes.  Best way to do it is to set up a listener wherever you need it:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(settingsChanged) name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

The only thing you need to make sure of is that you don't *change* any settings in your listener, or you get infinite recursion without a little more logic being added in.

I'd stay away from synchronizing because in my experience I found I had to run it twice.  But that's accidental behavior.  A listener will notify you when the new settings have been re-read from the store.

Comment: The downside to using this, is that it also fires when you change anything about `NSUserDefaults` yourself. So every time you call `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:someObject forKey:@"someKey"]` this notification is broadcast, and the method is called. Which is not what I (and presumably the asker) wants. Also, I haven't had any problems with `synchronize`, calling it only once worked fine.

Comment: This way is obviously better. Just update user-defaults, and do behavior change only in notification observer. And also, you have to apply any user-deafult changes in real-time during application running with multitasking of iOS4.